# How to find value of omega in CUSUM?

Tags: quality-control

I am trying to understand [CUSUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM) or `Cumulative Sum Control Chart`.

In the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM#Example) on above linked Wikipedia page, the formula for high CUSUM value indicating positive anomaly is given as:

$$S_{H_{n+1}}=\max(0, S_{H_n}+Z_n-\omega)$$

Similarly, formula for low CUSUM value, indicating negative anomaly is given by:

$$S_{L_{n+1}}=\max(0, S_{L_n}-Z_n-\omega)$$

However, I am not able to understand what is to be taken as the value of $\omega$ or omega in these formulae?

Comment: It's a tunable parameter.  Its value is adjusted to achieve an acceptable balance of the average run length of below-threshold values (when the process is out of control), which you want to be very long, against the expected time to observe an above-threshold value when the process is out of control, which you want to be very short.